# pushing UIDocumentIntractionController to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uidocumentinteraction

I am working on app, which actually like Pdf reader. Here, I am using `UIDocumentIntractionController` to read documents. But when I am calling `[documentController presentPreviewAnimated:YES]` my naviagation bar Color becomes like transparent and dim. I think it is because of presenting `ViewController`. To avoid that I am searching some mechanism where I can push my document to navigation stack instead presenting my document it. Guide me with ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

Comment: Hey I am already doing the same.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this.

```
- (BOOL)presentPreviewAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

UIDocumentInteractionController delegate method.

```
-(UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;  // if you want to show on your view controller.

   or
   return [self navigationController];  // if you want to push on your navigation controller.
}
```

Comment: Thank Dheeraj, I tried even this. But again here also it is same problem. Do we have any possibility where i can assign 'documentController' to 'UIViewController'?

Comment: @NOUMANPERVEZ try changed code this if you want into uiviewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks but not. I want something like assigning doucmentViewController to viewController, so that i can push ViewController instead of presentPreview.

Comment: [self navigationController] pushes UIDocumentInteractionController onto view controller.

Comment: Yeah I know. What I am searching is like instead of calling [documentController presentPreviewAnimated:YES],     [self.navigationController pushViewController:documentController animated:self].

Comment: go through this. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html